# Import SQL Server table to HDFS

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hbase, hive, sqoop

I am new to Hadoop and I have few queries regarding importing a table from SQL Server to hdfs using sqoop:

1. How to import whole database into hadoop using sqoop and any other way.
2. How can I import a single table which don't have primary key or is it possible to import SQL Server table which don't have primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How to import whole database into hadoop using sqoop and any other
   way.

   You can use [sqoop-import-all-tables](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1766722) to do that. Other way would
   be to write your own job using **DBInputFormat**.
2. How can I import a single table which don't have primary key or is
   it possible to import SQL Server table which don't have primary key.

   You can use **--split-by** to specify a column other than primary key column.

Answer (score 1):

For the 2nd question-How can I import a single table which don't have primary key or is it possible to import SQL Server table which don't have primary key.

When the table we import does not have a primary key we need to specify in the commands as to how many mappers are to be used. this can be specified by the options "-m" or "--Split-by" in the sqoop import

e.g:

$ bin/sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1 -username root -password password --table tableName --target-dir /user/tableName  -m 1